# Microsoft CRM 2013 reporting issue

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I have recently upgraded my microsoft dynamics crm from 2011 to 2013, all seemed to go accordingly however whenever i try to access any of my reports custom or out of the box they refuse to load. I either get an error which says the report cannot be loaded (rsprocessingaborted) [image] and if not this then it totally refuses to load almost as if some script is being blocked(2nd screenshot). I'm completely lost on this and any help will be greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try [turn on trace](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907490/en), restart IIS and reproduce an error. Then recheck trace file to get explanation of an error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I run a CRM migration.
Just follow the steps :
http://ashwaniashwin.wordpress.com/2013/07/21/crm-2011-reporting-error-the-report-cannot-be-displayed-rsprocessingaborted/

Note that this is the same as the steps in the Microsoft KB article, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/946585, which in summary involves ensuring if SQL Server Reporting Services service is running under the Local System account to add the NT Authority\SYSTEM to Security -> Logins in SQL Server Management Studio and to add this account in the User Mapping to the MSCRM_CONFIG and Organization_MSCRM databases with roles of CRMReader, public, and db_owner.